# Bootstrap images in rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I started to work with bootstrap, but Im currently having 2 problems with my images in rows
1. a strange padding appears below the image that I cannot eliminate
2. When the image is supposed to go left and a text next right next to it, the text doesnt align with the image and expands the row to align itself horizontally properly but vertically wrong. Pls help, been days fighting this

```
    <div class="firstline">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-eq-height">

        <article class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <h1>TEXT HERE</h1>
            <div class="pcp">
                <p>MORE TEXT HERE </p>
            </div>

            <div class="download">
                <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wop.android">
                    <img src="img/googleplay.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            </article>

            <article class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 image-container">
                <img class="img-responsive" height="80%" src="img/pru1/img1.png">
            </article>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem comes from the classes of your articles.
Bootstrap grid has 12 columns and I don't really get what you do in with your grid...

try making your articles this way

```
<div class="firstline">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-eq-height">

        <article class="col-lg-6">
            <h1>TEXT HERE</h1>
            <div class="pcp">
                <p>MORE TEXT HERE </p>
            </div>

            <div class="download">
                <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wop.android">
                    <img src="img/googleplay.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            </article>

            <article class="col-lg-6 image-container">
                <img class="img-responsive" height="80%" src="img/pru1/img1.png">
            </article>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I may don't get your issue, if I don't